# Script to find and replace words in multiple files

Tags: html, unix, sed

Good afternoon! I need a command to find and replace a directory path for another one, in multiple html files, here is a part of one html file:

```
<DIV STYLE="margin-top:6pt;margin-left:36pt;" >< FONT ID="f16" >
<A HREF="file:/export100/DOCS_AB/export200/ab.c" >
file:/export100/DOCS_AB/export200/ab.c</A></FONT></DIV>

<DIV STYLE="margin-top:6pt;margin-left:36pt;" >< FONT ID="f16">
<A HREF="file:/export100/DOCS_CD/export200/cd.c">
file:/export100/DOCS_CD/export200/cd.c</A></FONT></DIV>
```

The paths and the name of the .c files can vary. I had tried this :

```
find ./ -name *.html | xargs sed -i 's_/export_/media/pendrive_g'
```

I would like in return something like that:

```
<DIV STYLE="margin-top:6pt;margin-left:36pt;"><FONT ID="f16">
<A HREF="file:/media/pendrive/"nome_arquivo".c">
file:/media/pendrive/"nome_arquivo".c</A></FONT></DIV>
```

Thank you.

Comment: I did not down vote this. Nor do I have an answer, unfortunately. However, you forgot to describe the *actual* result of the code above (error, wrong output, ...) and how does it differ from the desired results?

Comment: I think this question should not be voted down like this. solutions are possible. So I vote you up.

Comment: @user3119414.my answer edited to include quotes on *.html. hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sed command line to substitute

```
sed 's#file:/.*\.c#file:/media/pendrive/\"nome_arquivo\".c#g'
```

if you are looking to find all .html file try something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
all_files=`find ./ -name '*.html'`
for file in $all_files ; do
    sed -i 's#file:/.*\.c#file:/media/pendrive/\"nome_arquivo\".c#g' "$file"
done
```